# combine products of 2 categories to one category

Tags: product, category

we created 4 categories.

Category 1, 2 , 3, 4

all have 50 + 50 + 50 + 50 products,

I created category 5 and category 6 ,

I want to add products of "category 1 & 2" to Category 5

I want to add products of "category 3 & 4" to Category 6.

is there any solution for this in magento site.

please hel pme to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a sql query, something like:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position) (
SELECT 5, product_id, position FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id IN (1,2)
);

INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position) (
SELECT 6, product_id, position FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id IN (3,4)
);
```

But I'm not sure whether this is enough

Comment: hi @fabian thanks a lot, do you have any idea related to changes in file?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you want to change aynthing in files? You need to change database content

Comment: i ran this in sql :

INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position) (
SELECT 83, product_id, position FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id IN (22,23)
);

but i got this :" #1062 - Duplicate entry '83-42' for key 'PRIMARY'"

for every category, i am getting above error

please help me to find solution.

Comment: The product is already part of the category. You can use INSERT IGNORE which ignores these errors (but all others too)

Comment: it's working fine, I just did this in demo site. are you sure there will be no problem from this query .
 is there any solutions by changing code?

Comment: Marius has a solution with code. And no with `But I'm not sure whether this is enough` I mean I don't know what side effects this has ;-)

Comment: that's fine, your solution is worked.... if Marius give solution means, surely it will works. but seems i have to 

do something else. can you please see his solution and tell me what else i have to do?

Comment: Just read `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts` to make sure you do everything this method is doing

Comment: i tried the sql query, but its adding the products to the category in the backend.

but when i opened the category link, its not displaying in the Products in that category. please check it from your end

Comment: Did you reindex?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Create a file called `clone.php` on the same level as `index.php` with this content

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);//just so you see the errors if any
Mage::app();//instantiate the application
$category1Id = 1;
$category2Id = 2;
$category5Id = 5;
//get the category instances
$category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category1Id);
$category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category2Id);
$category5 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category5Id);

//get products from the first 2 categories
$category1Products = $category1->getProductsPosition();
$category2Products = $category2->getProductsPosition();
//merge the products into one big array
$merged = array_merge($category1Products, $category2Products);
//assigned the merged products to category 5.

$category5->setPostedProducts($merged);
//save the category 5;
$category5->save();
```

When you are done call `clone.php` in the browser.

Comment: hi @Marius,

thanks for reply. can you please tell me where i have to add this code in which file and in which folder?

Comment: @user9434334345. See my update.

Comment: thanks @Marius clone.php => http://pastebin.com/vGJvPKVR , i put this in root of the site.... see here : http://demo.kidsdial.com/clone.php

Comment: You should change the values of the category ids to reflect your real ids. I just added 1, 2 and 5 for demo purposes.

Comment: sorry, i changed the category ids and placed clone.php in root of the site  =>http://pastebin.com/QD84T0mj

cleared the cache. than what else i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use this module:

https://github.com/klein0r/magento-category-merge

Helps a lot.